# In bash `expect` script autogeneratedd with `autoexpect`, there is a `^G` - what does it signify?

Tags: bash, expect

In bash `expect` script autogen'd with `autoexpect`,I am invoking line completion with a [TAB] in a situation where line completion offers no completions nor changes the input line.  The script excerpt looks like this:

```
send -- "dummyprog 1[TAB]"
expect -exact "^G"
```

where I have replaced a literal tab with the character `[TAB]` for visibility.

The `^G`, is literal.  I can see nothing about `^G` on the ubuntu man pages for [`expect`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/expect.1.html) or [`autoexpect`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/expect_autoexpect.1.html).

Is it a terminal control character?  Is it an artifact of the `expect` program?  What is it?

Comment: The shell sent a [bell character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character#Representations).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - that's it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character.